# PyZMQ ( ZeroMQ ) - How to get a subscription key from a SUB-socket?

Tags: sockets, zeromq, publish-subscribe, pyzmq

I would like to get the subscription key of a subscriber ( **`SUB`** ) socket after it has been set.

Say I have the following socket :

```
import zmq
ctx = zmq.Context.instance()
sub_sock = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
sub_sock.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:6667")
sub_sock.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "foo1".encode('ascii'))
```

What I want to do is something like this ( pseudo-code ) :

```
sub_key = sub_sock.get_sub_key().decode("ascii")
sub_key = subkey[:-1] + "2"  # "foo2"

# unsubscribe all keys
sub_sock.setsockopt(zmq.UNSUBSCRIBE, '')

# subscribe to new key
sub_sock.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, sub_key.encode('ascii'))
```

## Question :

However, I cannot discover a function that can retrieve the key of the subscriber socket. How can I retrieve the socket's subscription key?

## System :

- Python 3.6
- libzmq version: 4.2.5
- pyzmq version: 17.0.0

Comment: deserves [ **+1** ] for having quoted all version details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *How **can I** retrieve the socket's subscription key  <sub>( ... after it has been set )</sub> ?*

Yes, **one can**, but only on **`PUB`**-side ( well, actually the **`XPUB`** clone of the `PUB`-behaviour archetype ) if that have been carefully configured with `.setsockopt( { XPUB_VERBOSE | XPUB_VERBOSER }, 1 )` method so as to start serving channel-associated `(X)SUB`-s in this particular mode.

So, in an extreme need ( in a case of a SUB-side total loss of context or suffering from amnesia of it's own subscription-management ), one can setup the XSUB to also instantiate a utilitarian `XPUB`-instance with this additional `.setsockopt( { XPUB_VERBOSE | XPUB_VERBOSER }, 1 )` configuration, `{ .bind() | .connect() }` a link from-Home-Base to-Home-Base, and handle all the arrived `(X)SUB`-subscription details on-the-fly.

The native API documentation publishes all the details for doing this right.

A unique approach to learn one's own subscription details from a wire-tapping, yet doable.

---

### Final remarks :

The ZeroMQ topic-filter is designed in a way more complex manner and optimised for speed **( high throughput, low latency )**. It may handle units, hundreds, thousands, tens of thousands of subscriptions for each of the `{ .bind() | .connected() }` peers.

These design-aspirations and focus on performance was the reason, there is no such function for ex-post asking a "librarian" for finding all "***my own***" subscription keys ( no matter if never remembered or plain forgotten ).

One may also realise, that since API v4.x, the ZeroMQ native handling started to manage topic-filtering on the `(X)PUB`-side, while older API versions reported this performance-critical operation to be deferred onto each of the `(X)SUB`-side(s), at the cost of the increased cummulative volumes of raw-network traffic, as all messages ( yes, indeed, ALL MESSAGES ) went from `(X)PUB` to all `(X)SUB`-s. Did anyone mention security concerns here?

```
# unsubscribe all keys                        // THIS WILL NOT FLY THAT WAY
```

The same reasoning stands behind a "missing" API call, asking for "**forget all my own subscriptions**", but one has to explicitly unsubscribe, in a one by one manner, or properly `.close()` the `(X)SUB`-side socket-instance and rather re-instantiate another one on a green field basis and re-`{ .bind() | .connect() }` it back to the infrastructure, so as to meet the set goal en-bloc.

Answer (score 2):

There is no support to get the subscriptions from the **`SUB`** socket. You will need to store them in your own data structure ( list, map, etc )

**Some other info:**

A `SUB` socket supports multiple simultaneous subscriptions.

The line below does not unsubscribe **all** keys, its actually unsubscribing the key **`""`** which is a valid subscription.

```
# unsubscribe all keys
sub_sock.setsockopt(zmq.UNSUBSCRIBE, '')
```

You need to be explicit:

```
sub_sock.setsockopt(zmq.UNSUBSCRIBE, "foo1".encode('ascii'))
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that `''` does not mean all keys.